# JQuery Post caused permission denied warning in IE 6 and IE 7

Tags: jquery

I am using firefox 3 and IE 6, 7 to test if a simple php web page using JQuery Post to
pass some data to and from another server web page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

   $("#data\\[User\\]\\[name\\]").click(function(){ 

      var usr=$("#data\\[User\\]\\[name\\]").val();

   if(usr.length >= 4){     

      $("#username").append('<span id="loaderimg" name="loaderimg"><img align="absmiddle" src="loader.gif"/> Checking data availability,&nbsp;please wait.</span>');

      var url =  "http://mysite.com/site1/toavail/"+usr;    
      $.post(
      url,    
      function(data) {alert(data);});
}

   });
});
//-->
</script>


<table border=0 width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td>       
        <div id="username">
    <input type="text" name="data[User][name]" id="data[User][name]">
    </div>       
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In Firefox 3, the alert box showed empty message.
In IE 6 and IE 7, I got an error message saying "Permssion denied"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error appears because of the cross-domain Post.

You can read [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html) about PHP walkaround. Also check out this SO question: [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)